# Addon Domain CSS Not Working Properly

Tags: html, css, add-on

I've recently finished a website, and now that I've placed it in a folder as an addon domain, the CSS links aren't translating over properly. To get a better idea of what I'm talking about, examples below:

**CSS Working Properly:**
http://tinyurl.com/ctbrwdh

**CSS Not Translating Over (Addon Root Folder):**
http://tinyurl.com/b76onhl

If I setup the addon domain to point to the version of the website that works properly, it completely screws up the CSS and image links, and makes the site look even worse. So I've resolved to work with the current addon folder as it seems to be on the right path. What can I do to fix the CSS portions that aren't working properly?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thank you for all the help in the past Stackoverflow :)

I had to reference the current domain directory by using a "/" in my code:

Contact page for example:

Img reference using added "/"

img src="**/images/yellow-bar.jpg**" width="960" height="2" style="padding-bottom:2px;">